# No puedo acceder a un archivo creado con google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, google-documentos

Recientemente he creado un script, que hace una copia de una "plantilla" y la renombra dentro de una carpeta en la cual dispongo de permisos de editor para la carpeta y todos los archivos que en ella existen (se supone que debería de tener permisos de apertura y edición de los mismos).

El problema viene cuando intento acceder a dicho archivo mediante el siguiente comando

`var nuevoHipotecarioCopiado = DocumentApp.openById(idArchivo);`

Justamente el error me lo marca antes del `openById(idArchivo);`.

En mi cuenta, cuando ejecuto el script a través de un menú me funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando ejecuto el proyecto en la cuenta en la cual va a ser usado con asiduidad (en esta última cuenta también tengo los mismos permisos de editor en la carpeta desde la que hago la copia antes mencionada).

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
function generarHipotecario() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      nombreHoja = hojaActiva.getSheetByName(hojaActiva.getActiveSheet().getName()),
      plantillaHipotecario = DriveApp.getFileById("id de la plantilla"),
      carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById("id de la carpeta"),
      data = nombreHoja.getDataRange().getValues();
  const fila = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var obtenFecha = new Date();
  var mes = obtenFecha.getMonth();
  var dia = obtenFecha.getDate();
  var anyo = obtenFecha.getFullYear();
  switch (mes){
    case 0:mes = "Enero";break;
    case 1:mes = "Febrero";break;
    case 2:mes = "Marzo";break;
    case 3:mes = "Abril";break;
    case 4:mes = "Mayo";break;
    case 5:mes = "Junio";break;
    case 6:mes = "Julio";break;
    case 7:mes = "Agosto";break;
    case 8:mes = "Septiembre";break;
    case 9:mes = "Octubre";break;
    case 10:mes = "Noviembre";break;
    case 11:mes = "Diciembre";break;
  }
  var fecha = dia + " de " + mes + " de " + anyo;
  
  if ((hojaActiva.getActiveSheet().getName()).startsWith("Tot")){
    ui.alert("No se puede elegir una hoja de totales para el origen de los datos.");
  }else{
    if (data[fila-1]==null){
      ui.alert("Revisa los datos, la fila,está vacía.");
      //NOMBRE
    }else if (data[fila-1][2]==''){
      ui.alert("Revisa los datos, falta el Nombre para poder rellenar los datos.");
      //APELLIDOS
    }else if (data[fila-1][3]==''){
      ui.alert("Revisa los datos, faltan los apellios para poder rellenar los datos.");
      //DNI
    }else if (data[fila-1][7]==''){
      ui.alert("Revisa los datos, falta el DNI para poder rellenar los datos.");
      //EMAIL
    }else if (data[fila-1][6]==''){
      ui.alert("Revisa los datos, falta el email para poder enviar el correo electrónico.");
    }else if (fila==1){
      ui.alert("No se puede elegir la cabecera como origen de los datos.");
    }else{
      var nombre = data[fila-1][2];
      var apellidos = data[fila-1][3];
      var email = data[fila-1][6];
      var nombreCompleto = nombre+'_'+apellidos;
      var DNI = data[fila-1][7];
      
      var nuevoHipotecario = plantillaHipotecario.makeCopy("Hoja de Encargo Gastos Hipotecarios - ???? - " + nombreCompleto);
      var idArchivo = nuevoHipotecario.getId();
      **var nuevoHipotecarioCopiado = DocumentApp.openById(idArchivo);**

      var header = nuevoHipotecarioCopiado.getHeader();
      var body = nuevoHipotecarioCopiado.getBody();
      
      //Reemplazamos en la plantilla los campos
      const placeholders = ['{{NombreyApellidos}}','{{DNI}}'];
      body.replaceText('{{NombreyApellidos}}',nombreCompleto);
      body.replaceText('{{DNI}}',DNI);
      body.replaceText('{{Fecha}}', fecha);
      
      //Salvamos el documento, lo creamos en PDF y guardamos donde queramos
      nuevoHipotecarioCopiado.saveAndClose();
      
      var hipotecarioPdf = nuevoHipotecarioCopiado.getAs('application/pdf');
      hipotecarioPdf.setName(nuevoHipotecarioCopiado.getName()+".pdf")
      var docHipotecarioNuevoPdf = DriveApp.createFile(hipotecarioPdf);
      docHipotecarioNuevoPdf.moveTo(carpeta);
      Drive.Files.remove(nuevoHipotecarioCopiado.getId());
      
      //PREPARAMOS PARA ENVIAR EL CORREO ELECTRÓNICO
      var destinatario = email;//data[fila-1][6];
      var asuntoCorreo = "Hoja de encargo y autorización - ????? - Reclamación Gastos Hipotecarios.";// + nombreCompleto;
      var cuerpoCorreo = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mailHipotecario').evaluate().getContent();
      cuerpoCorreo = cuerpoCorreo.replace('#cliente#',nombre);
      
      //GENERAMOS EL DOCUMENTO DE REPRESENTACIÓN
      var idDesignacion = generarDesignacion();
      var representacion = DriveApp.getFileById(idDesignacion);

      //GENERAMOS EL ANEXO
      var idAnexo = anexo();
      var anexoNuevo = DriveApp.getFileById(idAnexo);

      GmailApp.sendEmail(destinatario,asuntoCorreo,cuerpoCorreo,
        {
          name:"documentos@????.com",
          replyTo:"documentos@???.com",
          htmlBody:cuerpoCorreo,
          attachments:[
            docHipotecarioNuevoPdf,
            representacion,
            anexoNuevo
          ]
        });
      
      //ELIMINAMOS EL PDF DE POSICIONES DEUDORAS CREADO Y LA CARTA DE DESIGNACION
      var idHipotecario=docHipotecarioNuevoPdf.getId();
      Drive.Files.remove(idHipotecario);
      Drive.Files.remove(idDesignacion);
      //GmailApp.sendEmail(destinatario,asuntoCorreo,cuerpoCorreo,{htmlBody:cuerpoCorreo,attachments:[docUsuraNuevoPdf]});
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Mensaje de error y ubicación del mismo]

Comment: *justamente el **error** me lo marca después del . justo antes del openById(idArchivo)* ... justamente ¿cuál es el **error**? Pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo o muestra una captura de pantalla.

Comment: Que error marca?

Comment: ¿Nos podrías mostrar el error que te marca?

Comment: La función no incluye la línea `var nuevoArchivo = DocumentApp.openById(idArchivo);`

Comment: Se modificó el post donde muestra el error que marca.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando el inicio de sesión múltiple, intenta usando el navegador en modo incognito / privado o bien usar una navegador o perfil de navegador para cada cuenta en los que no utilices el inicio de sesión múltiple.

Si lo anterior no te funciona, crea un proyecto de Google Cloud Platform (no olvides incluir la API de Google Drive) y vinculalo a tu proyecto de Google Apps Script